# Creating working copy for SVN on Enterprise Architect DBMS

Tags: database, svn, enterprise-architect

I am aware for Enterprise Architect and version control (using Subversion), projects where each user possesses their own project (.EAP) file, each user must have a local working copy checked out.

In a centralized DBMS repository which allows all users to work on the same .EAP project file rather than having their own, is it a better practice to consolidate to a working copy folder shared amongst all users? Or does each user need to maintain their own working copy similar to a non-DBMS team environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you choose another technology then .eap (which is atually MS Access) as underlying centralized repository.

But that set aside, the version control part stays the same. Each user has its own local working copy folder.  EA works with exclusive checkouts, regardless of having a central database, or distributed .eap files. So having a shared working folder would not work very well for that aspect.

What we do to make it a bit manageable is to tell users to map their working folder copy to a place in "home" folder (which in this case is mapped to the H:\ drive)
Each user then has `H:\SVN\Enterprise Architect\` as their working folder, but under the hood that gets registered as `\\servername\username\Documents\SVN\Enterprise Architect\` making each working folder unique to the SVN server.

PS. In my case this was for TFS, but I'm pretty sure the same principles apply for SVN.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you suggest another technology than .eap for a central repository? What alternatives are there and how do they compare?